# Using $_GET to get select option value from HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to figure out how the IF statement work with this $_GET select option in HTML, the thread says:

**Create a program which performs the selected arithmetic operation for the two input numbers. The PHP script has to print the calculation as well as its result. If both values aren't
given, print "You didn't input both numbers!". The used form is:**

```
 <form action="calculator.php" method="get">
 <input TYPE="text" name="num1">
 <select name="operator">
 <option value=1 selected>+</option>
 <option value=2>-</option>
 <option value=3>*</option>
 <option value=4>/</option>
 </select>
 <input TYPE="text" name="num2">
 <input type="submit" value="Send">     
 </form>
```

I have gotten this far:

```
<?php
       $first=$_GET['num1'];
       $second=$_GET['num2'];
       $operate=$_GET['operator'];
       $check = array($first,$second);
       $error = false;
       foreach($check as $sel){
           if(empty($sel)){
               $error = true;
           }
       }    
       while(!$error){
           if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==1){
               echo "{$first}" . "{$second}" . " = " . $first + $second . "\n";
           }
           if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==2){
               echo "{$first}" . "-" . "{$second}" . " = " . abs($first - $second) . "\n";
           }
           if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==3){
               echo "{$first}" . "*" . "{$second}" . " = " . $first * $second . "\n";
           }
           if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==4){
               echo "{$first}" . "/" . "{$second}" . " = " . $first / $second . "\n";
           }
           else{
               echo "You didn't input both numbers!";
           }
         break;
       }
?>
```

The expected output should be:

```
12 + 56 = 68
76 - 54 = 22
33 * 10 = 330
56 / 7  = 8
```

But instead I've got this:

```
68
12 - 56 = 44
12 * 56 = 672
12/56 = 0.21428571428571
```

Comment: Do not use || you must use && sign, || check either of condition

Comment: if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==4){
               echo "{$first}" . "-" . "{$second}" . " = " . abs($first - $second) . "\n";
           }
           if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==4){
               echo "{$first}" . "*" . "{$second}" . " = " . $first * $second . "\n";
           }
           if(!empty($operate) || $operate ==4){
               echo "{$first}" . "/" . "{$second}" . " = " . $first / $second . "\n";
           }  why used same condition for each

Comment: If you are running this on PHP 7.4.0 - 7.4.24, and have proper error reporting enabled, it would also show you the following warning: _"Deprecated: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence"_ So in PHP 8 this will get you the correct result, 12 + 56 = 68. But in lower versions, it is reversed - `+` and `-` have lower precedence, than the dot. So what this does, is determine the value of `"{$first}" . "{$second}" . " = " . $first` first, and _then_ it tries to add $second to that.

Comment: The string value `1256 = 12` parsed into an integer, will be `1256` again. You add `56` onto that, so the result is `1312`. Put braces around the addition part - `($first + $second)`

Comment: @SMI Sorry my mistake, I just edited the post. I also did change the || to && like you said, now the result show like this: `12*56 = 672`  \n                                                          You didn't input both numbers!

Comment: That's because your if/else logic is not correct. You are seeing the multiplication result, so that means `$operator` actually had the value `3`. But your `else` belongs to that last `if`, and that checks if it had the value `4`. It doesn't, and so of course you get the error message from the else branch.

Comment: The whole construct makes little sense. The `while` loop makes no sense whatsoever - the value of `$error` does not get changed inside the loop at all. And the error message for missing number inputs is what you should actually output depending on whether $error is true, but you output it in connection with whether the operator had any of the four defined values of not.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, @SMI and @CBroe about the idea of changing the || to &&, and put the braces at `($first + $second)`. Clearly I have complicated the situation myself, for that I reconstructed my code, and now it works as expected.

```
<?php
$first=$_GET['num1'];
$second=$_GET['num2'];
$operate=$_GET['operator'];
$check = array($first,$second);
$error = false;
foreach($check as $sel){
    if(empty($sel)){
        $error = true;
    }
}
if($error){
    echo "You didn't input both numbers!";
}
elseif(!empty($operate) && $operate == 1 ){
    echo "{$first}" . " + " ."{$second}" . " = " . ($first + $second) . "\n";
}
elseif(!empty($operate) && $operate == 2){
    echo "{$first}" . " - " ."{$second}" . " = " . abs($first - $second) . "\n";
}
elseif(!empty($operate) && $operate == 3){
    echo "{$first}" . " * " ."{$second}" . " = " . ($first * $second) . "\n";
}
elseif(!empty($operate) && $operate == 4){
    echo "{$first}" . " / " ."{$second}" . " = " . ($first / $second) . "\n";
}
?>
```